# CEFSharp ExecuteSyncAsync() send variable length parameter array

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am struggling to find the correct syntax for sending variable length parameters to a Javascript function.

I have tried this:
C# calling code:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object[] args =  {1,2,3 };
        browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(string.Format("test({0})",args));
    }
```

javascript being called:

```
 function test(args){
        alert("args length = " + args.length);
    }
```

The alert states that args is undefined.
I am doing something wrong  I  think?

Comment: Check the string your generating, I don't believe it will be in the correct format. You'll have something like `test(object)`, where you need to generate `test(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Yes I know the syntax was wrong. Seems strange the the CEFSharp guys havn't made this simpler. The WebBrowser supplied with VS is much simpler but unfortunately has version issues.

Comment: Your welcome to contribute a PR. Answering everyone's questions takes up a large chunk of my time.

Comment: The alert does not say that args is undefined, it says that args.length is undefined. You most likely received a string with the value "object[]" or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1372/files for an example, this extension method should simplify calling a method with params.

Needs a little more review before merging, should be in the `45.0.0` release of `CefSharp`.

For now you can just copy and paste the code. Contributions welcome. (Please post directly to `GitHub`)